# Strange javadoc warning: can not find method

Tags: java, javadoc

Having this class in a maven project:

```
package test;

public class A {
    /**
     * Used by {@link B#setC(C)}.
     * Used by {@link A.B#setC(C)}.
     * Used by {@link test.A.B#setC(C)}.
     */
    public class C {
    }

    public class B {
        public void setC(C c) {
            System.out.println("hello!");
        }
    }
}
```

Gives me this warning:

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\t>mvn clean javadoc:javadoc
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building t 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ t ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:javadoc (default-cli) > generate-sources @ t >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:javadoc (default-cli) < generate-sources @ t <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-javadoc-plugin:2.10.4:javadoc (default-cli) @ t ---
[WARNING] Source files encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO]
Loading source files for package test...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.8.0_101
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\A.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\A.B.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\A.C.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\package-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\package-summary.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\package-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\constant-values.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\class-use\A.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\class-use\A.C.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\class-use\A.B.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\test\package-use.html...
Building index for all the packages and classes...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\overview-tree.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\index-all.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\deprecated-list.html...
Building index for all classes...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-frame.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\allclasses-noframe.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\index.html...
Generating C:\Users\user\workspace\t\target\site\apidocs\help-doc.html...
3 warnings
[WARNING] Javadoc Warnings
[WARNING] C:\Users\user\workspace\t\src\main\java\test\A.java:9: warning - Tag @link: can't find setC(C) in test.A.B
[WARNING] C:\Users\user\workspace\t\src\main\java\test\A.java:9: warning - Tag @link: can't find setC(C) in test.A.B
[WARNING] C:\Users\user\workspace\t\src\main\java\test\A.java:9: warning - Tag @link: can't find setC(C) in test.A.B
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.521 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-02T10:10:28+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\user\workspace\t>
```

Why does javadoc say he can not find the method?

Comment: May be try `public void setC`?

Comment: @degr Same problem.

Comment: try to use `{@link A.B#setC(C)}.`

Comment: I know next to nothing about Javadoc. But it's interesting that it says "@link: can't find `setC(C)` in `test.A.B`" and not "@link: can't find `setC(test.A.C)` in `test.A.B`". Suppose you make it `{@link B#setC(test.A.C)}` or `{@link B#setC(A.C)}`, does that fix it? It's clearly resolving the `B` correctly, but...

Comment: try to do `Used by {@link test.A.B#setC(C)}.`

Comment: @degr updated question to all of your combination.

Comment: agree with @T.J Crowder, try to `Used by {@link test.A.B#setC(test.A.C)}.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `Used by {@link A.B#setC(A.C)}`.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.

Comment: @PeterRader: So [my guess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40928350/strange-javadoc-warning-can-find-method?noredirect=1#comment69067930_40928350) was right! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok, but it is a bug in javadoc because eclipse realy know what i mean if i strg+lmb the link.

Comment: @PeterRader: I'd think so. If it can resolve `B` (and it could, from the error), it should have been able to resolve `C`.

Comment: This is correct for Java 8. For Java 11, it works without that meaningless qualification.